# How to get initiating jnlp file name/dir in java?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I need way to detect which jnlp file which started current app. in my case I'm developing an application that is started by jnlp file that contains some additional info. I need to delete this jnlp file while app is closing. app cannot be started in any other way. is it possible to get this information, and if it is, how can i do it. thx for answers

Answer (score 1):

> I need to delete this jnlp file while app is closing.

That choice is not available to the developer.  It is a choice of the user, their JRE and system settings.

---

What *application feature* are you trying to implement from this?

Comment: Kind of single session acces app that is launched on some heavy secured machines. only file named XYZ.jnlp can be run due to safety policy (and on each machine this name is randomly generated once for each operator login on it). in jnlp file i'm passing some parameters like single acces hash to this app. user downloads jnlp which is dynamic generated at web server for each request.

Comment: Problem is that after each run user needs to manualy delete downloaded jnlp file, because next downloaded file would be named XYZ(2).jnlp. jnlp need to be scanned before download, so it cannot be launched directly from web page, it needs to be available on disk. lots of security restrictions.

Comment: @Misiakw :Did you find any solution for deleting downloaded jnlp file? In my case for every operation jnlp will be downloaded a hundred times a day, so i don't want my customer to get frustrated because of these many downloads :)

Comment: no, in my app i precoded some paths where jnlp files can be found, and at exit i check if jnlp exiss in any of those. if if exists - delete it.